# Less-than queries in a Lotus Model Repository

Tags: hanami, hanami-model

Is it possible to perform the following query in a Lotus::Model Repository?

```
def active
  query.where("publish_at >= #{Date.today}")
end
```

In Sequel, which Lotus::Model uses, you can do the above or you can pass it a block like so

```
where{publish_at >= Date.today}
```

This does not seem possible in Lotus as the `conditions` internal variable is a `Set` that requires a key and a value. I would love to know if anyone else has gotten this to work or a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query interface doesn't accept **yet** other values than the hash with a single key/value pair (eg. `where(name: 'Lotus')`. I'm planning to empower it soon.

**UPDATE:** the lambda style query is now implemented in master.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def self.created_after(date)
  query do
    where("created_at > #{date}")
  end
end
```

Comment: This results in the same KeyError.